# akka cluster fast handover

Tags: akka, distributed-system, redundancy, akka-cluster

I'm using an akka cluster singleton feature to have a single master node and multiple worker nodes. Worker nodes send results to the master and master persists them in a database. 
The problem is that it takes akka about 10 seconds to hand the singleton over, which results in 10 seconds downtime every time I deploy. Is there a way to make the singleton handover faster? Or is there some other approach to a `single master - multiple workers` pattern?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I am working on a similar problem.

Comment: No, we ended up using the slow failover.